# Android 1.5 api giving wrong output

Tags: android

I am working with android 1.5 api, I know it is deprecated, but its client requirement. I am using following code to read Contacts address but every time it give address count zero. I am not able find out what is the problem

```
private void getAddress(String _Id)
{
    Cursor curAddress=null;
    try
    {
        String addrWhere = Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ? AND " + Contacts.ContactMethods.KIND + " = ?"; 
        String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{_Id, Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_POSTAL_ITEM_TYPE};
        curAddress = _resolver.query(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);
        int i=0;
        int aCount = curAddress.getCount();
        String[] aType = new String[aCount];
        String[] aAddrss = new String[aCount];
        while(curAddress.moveToNext()) 
        {
            aType[i] = curAddress.getString(curAddress.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.TYPE));
            aAddrss[i] = curAddress.getString(curAddress.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.DATA));
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(StaticVariables.TAG, "getAddress: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if(curAddress!=null) curAddress.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The customer is not always right. :-( For my own apps, I never target below 1.6.  First, 1.5 has numerous issues that are fixed in 1.6.  Second, the G1 (1st shipping Android device) is upgraded to 1.6.  Third, the Android Support library (with Fragments, etc.) only goes back to 1.6.  Fourth, only 3 out of 1000 Android devices today use 1.5 (and 7 more use 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code I hope it work.

```
curAddress = getContext().getContentResolver().query(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);
```

Comment: thnx for reply, but _resolver is already initialized in class constructor and it is coming from main activity.